# Calculating Monthly Average over time with only Start and End Dates in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

In order to track our average headcounts and turnover trends, I had created a report in Power BI that essentially expanded a table with employee start/end information to give a record for each associate every day they were employed at the company.

While this solution works, I end up with a table containing millions of rows which does not seem very efficient.

I have looked into other possible solutions in DAX, but have not found anything that will give me the exact same output. It seems like most solutions rely on taking the timing from the start date and end date of a month and then averaging them, which is not quite what I am trying to do.

I have attached a simplified pbix file that shows the desired output of what I am trying to get at. Any advice would be appreciated.

[pbix example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/svcxw5edfrh5tds/headcount%20example.pbix?dl=0)

Comment: a snapshot table to handle this case is actually the best solution. What do you mean with "does not seem very efficient"? power BI is optimized to work with millions of rows without problems. Are you experiencing actual performance issues?

Comment: here is an article related to this kind of implementation https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/analyzing-events-with-a-duration-in-dax/

Comment: In your model you have both a date table and the auto date/time enabled. I'd suggest to disable the option auto date/time, since there is a custom date table (that is the best option)

Comment: @ sergiom when I say not efficient it is mainly related to the transforming/data refresh/load side of things, it definitely takes significantly longer to refresh than reports I would consider to be much more complex.

As I said the solution is working for now, but since it will be growing exponentially over time I worry about how it will perform in the future.

Comment: @sergiom that link you sent was just what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: If the snapshot tables are built on the datasource side or in Power Query, a possible alternative could be to move the snapshot creation  into DAX. Usually a refresh time a little bit longer performed once a day is better than slow reports. Anyway, I'm planning to think about a measure working without snapshots as soon as I have some free time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Final code ended up looking like this:

```
All Employees = countrows ('Employees')

Terminations = 
Calculate(
    Countrows('Employees'),
    USERELATIONSHIP('Employees'[End Date],'Calendar'[Date])
)


Active Employees = 
AVERAGEX(
    VALUES('Calendar'[Date]),
    VAR CurrentDate = 'Calendar'[Date]
    VAR HiredBeforeCurrentDate =
        Filter(
            ALL('Employees'[Start Date]),
            'Employees'[Start Date] <= CurrentDate
        )
    VAR HiredAfterCurrentDate = 
        FILTER(
            ALL('Employees'[End Date]),
            OR('Employees'[End Date] >= CurrentDate, isblank('Employees'[End Date])
            )
        )
    RETURN
        CALCULATE(
            Countrows('Employees'),
            HiredBeforeCurrentDate,
            HiredAfterCurrentDate,
            ALL('Calendar')
        ))
```